# C# grammar "base"

Tags: c#, grammar

I am looking into the grammar of C# 5.0 and don't quite understand the use of "base". In the reference manual, there is a notion of "base access" defined as:

```
base-access:
    base   .   identifier
    base   [   expression-list   ]
```

Where `base` is a keyword, and it appears that this is the only case. However, I encounter C# inputs such as

```
base.WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>(node, diagnostics);
```

Can someone point me out which grammar rule this statement refers to? As 'base' appears to be a normal keyword, not contextual, I assume that there should be a specific grammar rule for this case, and `base` cannot simply be an identifier.

Comment: I cannot point you to a specific grammar rule, but I can tell you that `base` is used to refer to a class from which another is derived. It is generally used when overriding a method or constructor, to access state or behavior of the super class.

Comment: It might help if you could provide a link to the C# 5.0 reference manual

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. I'm not sure how to interpret "it appears that this is the only case" nor "which grammar rule this statement refers to" (given that *multiple* grammar rules will be involved in the interpretation of any particular statement)

Comment: @Justin http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Since `base.` must be followed by an identifier, and `WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>` is not an identifier, and there does not appear to be any rule permitting a *base-access* to be followed by a *type-argument-list*, how is the expression syntactically valid? That's the question I'm asking myself after reading this question, and that's what I think Ali is asking.

Comment: The first case should be `base . identifier type-argument-list(opt)`, which is what `base.WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>` maps to. Perhaps you've got an older or incomplete version of the spec?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet The C# 5 specification installed as part of Visual Studio 2013 is what I've got on my computer, and it contains the same productions as in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it *should* actually be

```
base-access:
    base   .   identifier type-argument-list_opt
    base   [   expression-list   ]
```

... which would make it just like member-access:

```
member-access:
    primary-expression   .   identifier   type-argument-list_opt
    predefined-type   .   identifier   type-argument-list_opt
    qualified-alias-member   .   identifier   type-argument-list_opt
```

In other words, in an expression

```
base.WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>(node, diagnostics);
```

only

```
base.WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>
```

is the *base-access* part - and the rest is parsed as it would be for other calls such as `x.WithAdditionalDiagnostics<TNode>(node, diagnostics)`.

From section 7.6.8 of the C# 5 spec:

> At binding-time, *base-access* expressions of the form `base.I` and `base[E]` are evaluated exactly as if they were written `((B)this).I` and `((B)this)[E]`, where `B` is the base class of the class or struct in which the construct occurs. Thus, `base.I` and `base[E]` correspond to `this.I` and `this[E]`, except `this` is viewed as an instance of the base class.

Without the additional *type-argument-list<sub>opt</sub>* though, I think your existing expression wouldn't parse.

This is actually specified correctly in the [4th edition of the ECMA-334 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf); I shall raise it as a bug with the C# specification (and make sure it doesn't get broken for the 5th edition).

Comment: There seem to be references to multiple different versions of the spec. The one I have in front of me of C# 5 defines the grammar rules like this: *base-access: base . identifier base [ argument-list ]*. http://i.imgur.com/iuScjTQ.png

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No, that's the same spec I've got - I'm saying there's a bug in the first option there.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I thought you were correcting the OP. Makes sense then.

Comment: @JonSkeet So it's a bug in the specification. One question: do you  know why type-argument-list is not part of the invocation expression (as in Java)? They appear to be part of the member access. I'm not familiar with C#, but do people write `A.X<Blah>`? what does it mean?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, people absolutely write `A.X<Blah>`. It means "call the method `X` in `A` (or the type of `A`) with type argument `Blah`." Personally I think it looks a *lot* nicer there than straight after the dot as in Java. It's just a different kind of argument :) I can't say much about the subtleties of the grammar, but perhaps the type argument list is required in order to perform member lookup, as members in C# can be overloaded by generic arity. (At least, that's another difference between C# and Java which may be relevant here...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! what I actually meant was that can `A.X<Blah>` exist on its own without a call, I mean without being part of a call `A.X<Blah>(arg1, arg2)` say? Do we have generic member access in C# that is not part of a call?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, it can, as a method group conversion: `Func<string> x = Foo<string>;` is valid if `Foo` has a signature of `T Foo<T>()` for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks :) Interesting feature!